# Is there a way to make a NxM table where each cell has two subcells on the bottom?

Tags: php, html-table

How do I make a NxM table where each cell has two rows and its second row has two columns, but by using rowspan or colspan? I want to make something like this:
[image]
Here is my attempt.

Artikal.php:

```php
public function get_html()
{
    $html = "";
    $html .= "<td>";

    if (isset($this->sifra) && isset($this->naziv) && isset($this->cena) && isset($this->kolicina)) {
        if ($this->kolicina > 0) {
            $html .= "<img src=\"images/" . str_replace(" ", "-", $this->naziv) . jpg\" width=\"100\">";
            $html .= "<br>";
            $html .= "<span class=\"sifra\">{$this->sifra}</span>";
            $html .= "<span class=\"cena\">{$this->cena} DIN</span>";
        } else {
            $html .= "<img src=\"images/none.png\" width=\"100\">";
            $html .= "<br>";
            $html .= "<span class=\"sifra\">{$this->sifra}</span>";
            $html .= "<span class=\"cena\">{$this->cena} DIN</span>";
        }
    } else {
        $html .= "<img src=\"images/none.jpg\" width=\"100\">";
        $html .= "<br>";
        $html .= "<span class=\"sifra\">X</span>";
        $html .= "<span class=\"cena\">X</span>";
    }
 
    $html .= "</td>";
    return $html;
}
```

index.php

```php
if (isset($artikli)) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++) {
        echo "<tr>";

        for ($j = 0; $j < 9; $j++)
            echo $artikli[$i * 9 + $j]->get_html();

        echo "</tr>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, make the big cell a `colspan="2"` and the small cells are then another row of the table

Comment: @RiggsFolly No, this doesn't do what I want.

Comment: It will do what you want, but it may be a little to complex for you to get your head around without a bit of a practice

Comment: By the way, lovely drawing, now it is almost completely unreadable and adds nothing but confusion

Comment: RiggsFolly makes a sensible suggestion. It's unclear why you think it wouldn't work for you. Why not try it and see

Comment: @ADyson Because I've tried it and it messed up my table. I want to have a single cell at indexes (i, j) have a top row and a bottom row with two columns.

Comment: Messed up your table how, exactly? Here's a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/rL7hov91/1/ It looks like what you asked for in the picture. It's hard to see what the problem could be (unless you didn't implement it correctly, of course).

Comment: @ADyson How do I combine it with for loop?

Comment: Each iteration of the loop would output a new row, I expect. Are you stuck on some specific aspect of achieving that?